# Orbeon XML contains links to temporary files on send

Tags: tomcat, orbeon

After upgrading from Orbeon 4.65 to 4.10, we are experiencing problems with attached files to certain forms in Orbeon Form Runner.

For certain forms (only a few), the XML that Orbeon Form Runner is posting to our service contains links to the temporary files uploaded to Tomcat.

```
<Fuldmagt filename="img-thing.jpg" mediatype="image/jpeg" size="9883">
file:/C:/Users/ewp/IdeaProjects/blanketservice_src/tools/v4-10/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/temp/xforms_upload_18806697738900846.tmp?filename=img-thing.jpg&amp;mediatype=image%2Fjpeg&amp;size=9883&amp;mac=1ff3fe177cad65bf0f9b2747044e9aba73b68f12
</Fuldmagt>
```

The form definition is defined as follows:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14750843/form.xml

The send process is defined as follows:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*"
   value='require-uploads
          then validate-all
          then save(draft="false")
          then send(
            uri      = "http://localhost:8080/ServiceGateway/receiveBlanketData/request",
            method   = "POST",
            replace  = "none", 
            content  = "xml"
          )
          then send(
            uri      = "/../receipt/",
            method   = "GET",
            replace  = "all",
            content  = "xml"
          )
          recover error-message(message = "Blanketten kunne ikke indsendes. Kladden er gemt, prøv venligst senere.")'/>
```

Oddly, the XML which is stored in Orbeon Form Data has links to the persisted files:

```
<Udbyttenota filename="img-thing.jpg" mediatype="image/jpeg" size="9883">
/fr/service/persistence/crud/skat/Ansoegning_om_fritagelse_for_dansk_udbytteskat_2/data/26fa1462f450af70bf269c17bd0a80dc39a5a2ae/035e35acc559e0bae30a6bf8144aad1e76587131.bin
</Udbyttenota>
```

So it seems that Orbeon is POSTing the XML before the files have been persisted - or at least until the temporary file links in the XML have been replaced with the persisted ones.

Can I do something to make sure that the SEND isn't initiated before the links have been replaced in the XML?

Comment: This is surprising: once the data is saved, the paths are updated in the data and so the data you are receiving with the `send` should be the same. It might be a bug, or something else happening.

Comment: I am not reproducing this with 4.10. I've taken a verbatim 4.10, set this [properties-local.xml](https://gist.github.com/avernet/6973e68d807dc017679a), created a form with just 1 File Attachment field, published, opened the `/new` page, attached a file, hit *Submit*, checked the result on [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/1alf9hv1?inspect), and I do [see there](http://i.imgur.com/B52n9In.png) the proper URI being included in the XML. Do you see something different if you do the same?

Comment: Maybe, I did not state clearly enough in my question, but the problem only occurs for certain form definitions (Currently, only two of our many forms). For the remaining forms, the links are replaced as expected. I have added a link to the form definition to my original question

Comment: Is this still a current issue? I don't think we got to the bottom of it.

Comment: Hi @ebruchez. No, I never found a solution for the problem, but I found a workaround that work in our case. 

Luckily, the service we are posting to, also has access to Orbeons database. So to solve the problem, I check if any of the files that are attached in the form has "file:/" in their URI. If they do, I look in the orben_form_data table and retrieve the XML from here, as this oddly enough contains the persisted URI. 

Of course, if I didn't have this option, there would be no way to retrieve the correct URI.

Comment: Good to hear you have a workaround, but of course I am still puzzled by the issue. Anyway if it becomes a real problem again, let me know.